# STM32 Power connections question

Tags: stm32

When incorporating the STM32F7 MCU onto your own board design, is it necessary to connect supporting circuitry (analogue supply filtering etc) to the VDDA, VCAP pins if not using any of the analogue parts of the chip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. None of the  STM32 chips I've worked with would boot without VDDA.

Check your [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f722ic.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> ## 3.14 Power supply schemes
>
> V<sub>SSA</sub> , V<sub>DDA</sub> = 1.7 to 3.6 V: external analog power supplies for ADC, DAC, Reset
>   blocks, RCs and PLL. V<sub>DDA</sub> and V<sub>SSA</sub> **must** be connected to V<sub>DD</sub> and V<sub>SS</sub>, respectively.

Not much room for interpretation in a "must".

Comment: for the internal oscillator and even more importantly even the reset logic. The thing literally can't turn on without.